# How ActionController instance variable @test="123" is accessible in Action View in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How ActionController instance variable `@test="123"` is accessible in ActionView? Similarly how helper method is available in ActionView? What's core architecture? What is the purpose of ActionPack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller.rb

```
  def index
    @test = "123"
  end
```

in index.html.erb

```
  <%=  @test %>
```

Comment: no, i think you don't got my point i know this thing my question that what is core architecture that make it possible.

Comment: that is a scope of instance variable. you have to look for then the different variables and there scopes.

Comment: i know there is scope of variables, you are talking on abstract level.